# preg_replace str_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, str-replace

Пытаюсь заменить вывод х-ки товара.
Написал такой код:

```
$product['property_html'] = preg_replace('~(.*?Цена *:\s.*?\s)-\s(\d+\sруб\.)(.*?)$~', '${1}' . '$3', $product['property_html']);
$product['property_html'] = str_replace('Цена *','Выбранные дни аренды', $product['property_html'] );
echo $product['property_html']
```

Изначально `$product['property_html']` выглядит вот так:

```
Цена 2 [prop attr=3500]: 1 день - 3500 руб.
```

Я хочу это всё убрать и просто выводить

```
Выбранные дни аренды: 1 день
```

Но отказывается работать - только если в `str_replace` я четко напишу Цена 2, а у меня есть просто Цена, Цена 3 и тд. И никак не обрезается "- 3500 руб."

Comment: Чот регулярка выглядит как случайный набор символов xDD Почему не взять что-то типа `\d+ д[а-яё]+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = 'Цена 2 [prop attr=3500]: 1 день - 3500 руб. И так далее.';
// строка переводу не подлежит
$pattern = '~Цена[^:]*:\s*(\S+\s+\S+)\s+-\s+\S+\s+\S+~u';
$repl = 'Выбранные дни аренды: $1.';
$str = preg_replace($pattern, $repl, $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Результат

```
string(72) "Выбранные дни аренды: 1 день. И так далее."
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1076a4a580bb8140623c44a120a5fbc9802ce94e

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!